# Azure Web App: Cannot add a VNET Restriction Rule using PowerShell when VNET is on a different subscription

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I have a web application in azure and I want to make sure that only my build server (or any other VM on the same subnet) are the only ones which are able to access the SCM site. I thought the most obvious thing would be to create an access restriction rule and in fact that works, I am able to create it from the portal with no issue whatsoever.

The problem, however, happens when I try to automate this using powershell. My build server subnet is located on a subscription different from the one where my web application is.

I am executing the following powershell script:

```
$subnetId = "/subscriptions/$VNETSubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$VNETResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$buildServerVNET/subnets/$buildServerSubNet"
Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule -ResourceGroup $webAppRg -WebAppName $webAppname -Name VNETAccess -Priority 1000 -Action Allow -SubnetId $subnetId
```

And I get the following error:

```
Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule : The client '{{my user credential}}' with object id '81fa4eb1-5553-4daa-af44-3c717b19eda2' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/read' over scope '/subscriptions/{{websiteSubscriptionId}}/resour
ceGroups/{{VNETResourceGroup}}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/{{buildServerVNET}}/subnets/{{buildServerSubNet}}' or
the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

The error seems to indicate that the cmdlet is searching for the subnet on the same subscription id than the website instead of the subscription where the subnet is located, since the resourceId string that is being returned on the error messsage has the wrong subscription Id. It is using the one where the website is instead of using the one where the build server is.

What else needs to be done in order to create this rule through powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is confused.

In fact, after my validation, you need to add the `-IgnoreMissingServiceEndpoint` parameter when adding a subnet from a different subscription. Read this GitHub case [WebApp:Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule.md - incorrect use of subscription context over SubnetId param](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/13818)

> When using a subnet from a different subscription, we cannot validate
> the subnet to see if the correct service endpoint (Microsoft.Web) has
> been set. If you use **-IgnoreMissingServiceEndpoint** the rule can be
> added.

Comment: I will try your suggestion. However, the resource Id that is being shown on the error is not the right one. It shows the subscription id of the subscription where the web application is and not the subscription id where the VNET is. On top of that I do have contributor access to that VM.

I checked the source code of the cmdlet and it has this line

var subnetResourceId = NetworkClient.ValidateSubnet(subnet, VirtualNetworkName, subNetResourceGroupName, DefaultContext.Subscription.Id);

So I do not know if this is possible as it will always use the subscription id of my context

Comment: I can add the VNET from the portal without any issues. I'm also a contributor on the VNET

Comment: I can not reproduce this error message. The error message seems confused because, in fact, we can not access the subnet in a different subscription from our current active subscription context. The real error is "not found" on my side. I have the same experience that I can do it from the portal but not PowerShell. If you add the parameter `-IgnoreMissingServiceEndpoint`.  The PowerShell works.

Comment: Hi I just tried adding your suggestion and it did work. Thanks a lot for your help